# C++ - getting variables set in a different class, from a different class

Tags: c++

I have three classes. In class `a.cpp` I have an int `i` and a function to set and to get the int `i`

```
int i = 0
void setI(int number)
{
    i = number;
}
int getI()
{
     return i;
}
```

In class `b` I'm setting `i` to a certain value.

```
A aObject
aObject.setI(5);
```

Now, if I print the value of `i` onto the screen I get the value, that I set it to.

In class `c` however, I want to print that value using the same method as I used in class `b`,

```
A aObject
cout << aObject.getI();
```

but when I do that, I get the default value of `i` (which is 0).
How do I get the value I changed it to before?

Comment: Just as an FYI, it is not a good idea to format large blocks of code with backticks. To format an entire block, indent the lines in it by four characters, or highlight the block and click the curly braces button in the formatting toolbar.

Comment: Seems like a scope issue. Also, there are a lot of unknowns for us because we don't know what you are doing with your classes. It would be best for you to post the code for us to look at.

Why would you have Class B set the value of the A instance, and Class C read the A instance?

Comment: Thanks, I didn`t really know how to format properly.

Comment: `A aObject` makes a new object. Why would it have the value you set elsewhere?

Comment: Im new to c++, sorry. So, what you`re saying is, that if I use pointers, it should work?

Comment: Seems that you have two different instances of class `A`. You gave both instances the name `aObject`. But the same name does not make it automatically referring to the same instance of the class `A`.

Comment: `static` is what you want. See [here](http://ideone.com/E0gTTU). If you do this, people won't like you.

Comment: I didn't realised, that I'm creating two different objects (as I said, new to c++). Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @PotatoIng_ If you accept the answer of @George you still call two different objects. I don't think you understood the meaning of the keyword `static`in that context and the meaning of the scope (life-time) of instances of classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different objects, their fields are different entities stored in different places. You set one and read another. You probably want to have one single object defined globally (or somewhere else where it's visible from both classes). Or, if you still want to have different objects but same field for all objects (class field), take a look at `static`.

Comment: This method managed to fix the program and I understand the error, which was what I wanted. Sorry, that that wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: @PotatoIng_ But static means that the field has the same values for all instances of your class. If you just want to access an arbitrary field of an instance of a class in another place as you have created that instance you have to pass it around. So the solution suggested may work for you, but may do too much. Means that making a field `static` is nearly the same like using global variables.

Comment: @cwschmidt It's a very simple program, I don't think, that it would matter that much. But for future references, what would you suggest?

Comment: @PotatoIng_ Without further context, it's hard to suggest anything. But as a rule of thumb: Avoid global variables whenever you can and prefer non-static fields, because static field are similar to global variables. But, referring to my first answer: The suggested solution with `static` may work for you, but I doubt you completely understood *why*, because you said you didn't recognize that you used two different objects and the `static`didn't change the fact that you use two different objects, it just made the scope for `i` more global (and this may indicate bad design).

Comment: You're right, that I can't say I understand something, If I don't know everything about it. And again, It's not really even a project, so I took the first answer that worked. There's not much context in here, I'm in process of learning c++ and this was a project to test a thing I'm learning currently. That's all it does. Thank you, for informing me on `static` however.